# Split comma separated string to count duplicates

Tags: c#

I have the following data in my database (comma separated strings):

"word, test, hello"
"test, lorem, word"
"test"
...
etc

How can I transform this data into a Dictionary whereby each string is separated into each distinct word together with the number of times that it occurs, i.e.

```
{"test", 3},  {"word", 2}, {"hello", 1}, {"lorem", 1}
```

I will have approximately 3000 rows of data in case this makes a difference to any solution offered. Also I am using .NET 3.5 (and would be interested to see any solution using linq)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;

Dictionary<string,int> result = strings.SelectMany(s => s.Split(','))
                                       .GroupBy(s => s.Trim())
                                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize how nice C# has gotten with the addition of lambdas! This is like reading Lisp ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is something like a pseudocode(haven't tried to compile it)

```
List<string> allRows = getFromDatabase();

var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (string row in allRows)
{
   string[] words = row.Split(',');

   foreach (string word in words)
      if (result.ContainsKey(word))
         result[word]++;
      else
         result.Add(word, 1);
}
```