# Which is better approach for Finding Duplicates in a Comma Separated String?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following two approaches. Approach 1 uses a `HashSet` and List. Second approach uses `Sorting of Array`.

Which is better in terms of `processing speed`

1. when there are many records?
2. when there is small number of records?

CODE

```
        string entryValue = "A,B, a , b, ";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(entryValue.Trim()))
        {

            //APPROACH 1
            bool isUnique = true;

            //Hash set is unique set  -- Case sensitivty Ignored
            HashSet<string> uniqueRecipientsSet = new HashSet<string>(entryValue.Trim().Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()),StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase );

            //List can hold duplicates
            List<string> completeItems = new List<string>(entryValue.Trim().Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));

            if (completeItems.Count != uniqueRecipientsSet.Count)
            {
                isUnique = false;
            }


            //APPROACH 2
            bool isUniqueCheck2 = true;
            string[] words = entryValue.Split(',');
            Array.Sort(words);

            for (int i = 1; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if (words[i].ToLower().Trim() == words[i - 1].ToLower().Trim())
                {
                    isUniqueCheck2 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }


            bool result1 = isUnique;
            bool result2 = isUniqueCheck2;


        }
```

REFERENCES:

1. [Split comma separated string to count duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617896/split-comma-separated-string-to-count-duplicates)
2. [MSDN Blog - Find Duplicates using LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/19/find-duplicates-using-linq.aspx)

Comment: What's stopping you from using `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and measuring it yourself?

Comment: Your second approach is flawed in that you sort before trimming spaces.

Comment: @cjk. That's a good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your first approach:

```
List<string> completeItems = new List<string>(entryValue.Trim().Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()));
isUnique = completeItems.Count == completeItems.Distinct().Count();
```

This would eliminate multiple splitting, and hide the hash set behind the call of `Distinct()`. Note that the `if` statement is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The hashset approach is O(n); the sort approach is O(n log n).

However, an even quicker option would be to short-circuit the hashset approach by stopping as soon as you first see a duplicate:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueRecipientsSet
    = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool isUnique = true;

foreach(var item in entryValue.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()))
{
    if (!uniqueRecipientsSet.Add(item))
    {
        isUnique = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

You *could* hide the `foreach` loop in LINQ:

```
HashSet<string> uniqueRecipientsSet
    = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
bool isUnique = entryValue.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim())
    .All(i => uniqueRecipientsSet.Add(i));
```

This is "LINQ-with-side-effects" but it *does* reduce the whole thing to two lines.

You could write your own `AreAllDistinct` extension method to avoid the side-effect-iness:

```
public static bool AreAllDistinct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    HashSet<T> checker = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (var t in T)
        if (!checker.Add(t))
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool isUnique = entryValue.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim())
    .AreAllDistinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have used [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) yourself. The first approach is a little bit faster:

```
1) 00:00:00.0460701  2) 00:00:00.0628364
```

Each approach 10000 repitions (just a simple way to measure the time)